# JQuery Ajax not sending data to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

myscript.js below is outputing:

```
[{"orcamento":"10","atual":"20","desvio":"","data":"2015-01-01","nome_conta":"BBB","nome_categoria":"abc","nome_entidade":"def"}]
```

myscript.js:

```
if (addList.length) {
            $.ajax($.extend({}, ajaxObj, {
                data: { "addList": JSON.stringify(addList) },
                success: function (rows) {
                    $grid.pqGrid("commit", { type: 'add', rows: rows });

                },
                complete: function () {
                    $grid.pqGrid("hideLoading");
                    $grid.pqGrid("rollback", { type: 'add' });
                    $('#consola').text(JSON.stringify(addList));
                }
            }));
        }
```

The JSON data above has to be sent to my script.php below:

```
if( isset($_POST["addList"]))            
{
    $addList = json_decode($_POST["addList"], true);
    var_dump ($addList);
    echo "test";
    exit();
}
```

Although the data is correct and myscript.php is being called it isn't returning anything. I get:

```
NULLtest
```

I tried using GET, instead of POST but the result is the same, what is wrong with the code above?

EDIT:
Here's the ajaxObj used in the ajax request:

```
var ajaxObj = {
        dataType: "json",
        url:"../myscript.php",
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
            $grid.pqGrid("showLoading");
        }
    };
```

Comment: Minor remark: you don't _send data to PHP_, you _make an HTTP request to a server_ [which may have a PHP app listening].

Comment: Add this on you .ajax call: type: 'POST',

Comment: Maybe I'm just missing it, but I don't see a URL anywhere in that call to $.ajax

Comment: @moonwave99: thanks, I'll upgrade my lingo ;)

Comment: What do you get if you `console.log(addList)` before the ajax request?

Comment: I'm using an object (ajaxObj) to configure the request. I'll edit my question above and show it

Comment: @KevinB I get ReferenceError: addList is not defined

Comment: that doesn't make sense. you just tested it's length, it shouldn't give you a reference error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PHP Docs on [json_decode](https://www.php.net/json_decode):

`NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.`

So it is most likely that there is some error in your JSON data that is preventing json_decode from parsing it correctly, I've ran that snippet through [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com) and it does say that it's valid JSON, but it's worth checking a larger sample of the data you send to the server for inconsistencies.

Other than that, is there any reason that you are calling JSON.stringify on the data object prior to sending to the server? I would try just sending the object itself as the data parameter of your AJAX call like so:

```
        $.ajax($.extend({}, ajaxObj, {
             data: { "addList": addList },
            success: function (rows) {
                $grid.pqGrid("commit", { type: 'add', rows: rows });

            },
            complete: function () {
                $grid.pqGrid("hideLoading");
                $grid.pqGrid("rollback", { type: 'add' });
                $('#consola').text(JSON.stringify(addList));
            }
        }));
```

And see if that helps:

**EDIT**

I should have noticed in my original answer, you will not need to call json_decode on your posted data, jQuery encodes the data as post parameters correctly for you; It should be accessible within your PHP script as an associative array, try replacing your current var_dump statement in your PHP  `var_dump($_POST['addList'][0]['orcamento']);` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping, with the suggested changes, I get from PHP: "<b>Warning</b>:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in ..."

Comment: Have you tried my recommendation in the edit to my question, to see if that helps?

Comment: Yes, I've just tested it. It is returning: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use string offset as an array in

Comment: renove the JSON.stringify line and just send the JSON objecy and try agaon

Comment: I get the message: "<b>Warning</b>:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>" and NULL

Comment: lol remove the json decode AND the json stringify. jQuery will encode your json object as post parameters meaning it will be available within your php script as an associative array inside the $_POST superglobal

Comment: sorry, I messed up the php file in the server. Using your recommendation I get: "string(1) "0" test"

Comment: im on my phone so can't really write out an example here but I will when I get into my office, in the meantime can you do a pastebin of your current js and php and put the link here?

Comment: Sure, I've used jsfiddle instead. In the CSS separator, I've pasted the PHP code, but it should give you an idea. Have a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/nuno/xDWJh/2/

Comment: Does the array key 'orcamento' contain the string "0"? I would suggest to keep your code as you have posted in your pastebin, but change your vardump to read var_dump($_POST['addList']); - see if the results are anything like you expect?

Comment: Yes, I guess the question is solved. I'm able to grab the array length and the contents of each element! Now it's just a matter of building a loop with an INSERT query. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :) for future reference, the crux of the issue was that jQuery encodes json objects as post parameters automagically, so you do not need to amend the json on the way to the server, or decode as json on the server, those things are done for you - glad it's solved though

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be sure you are posting to a php file, use firebug or similar tools to track your script..

I don't see the part you defined the target PHP file on your javascript file..

A regular javascript code can look like this :

```
jQuery.ajax({
     type : "post",
     dataType : "json",
     url : 'target.php',
     data : {foo:bar },
     success: function(response) {
        // do something with response...
     }
});
```

If you see that you are posting to the right php file the right parameters on firebug, try to use `$_REQUEST` if `$_POST` not working..

Firebug will show you the response of PHP file.. so do a `print_r($_REQUEST['addList'])` to see what is going on...